# How to use React Hooks inside Class Component "useWindowDimensions"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, responsive-design

I am working on React Native app for which I have all the components are class based. Now I have to implement the screen rotation functionality that change the design according to screen rotation. I am trying to use the library `useWindowDimensions` from react native, but it throws error that hooks can't be called from non functional component.

Can anyone tell how to use hooks in class based component, or any other approach to detect the screen dimension to make screen responsive for screen rotation?

Update: I used the event listener to get the screen orientation, but the problem is the global variable are not updating in the stylesheets, but it is working in inline styling. Here is the minimum viable example code:

```
   import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

    var screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
    var screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
    
        class ABC extends Comp {
        
        componentDidMount() {
        Dimensions.addEventListener("change", (handler) => 
        this.forceUpdate();
        width = handler.window.width;
        }
        render(){
        
        return(
        // If I directly access width here, I get updated value, but if I use stylesheet, I am getting old value
        )
        }
        
        }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container:{
width: screenwidth
}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

A basic functional component looks like:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const { height, width } = useWindowDimensions();
    return <>height: {height}, width: {width}</>;
}
```

You can't use hooks in class based Components.

Comment: yes.. but my all components are already Class based, so how to use this hook in my Class based component?

Comment: You can't. React seems to be moving away from class based Components in favor of functional Components.

Comment: Any hooks like functionality I can do to get the current orientation whenever the orientation of device change, currently it stuck until I refresh the app?

Comment: You could always just distill and copy the code from the hook https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/8bd3edec88148d0ab1f225d2119435681fbbba33/Libraries/Utilities/useWindowDimensions.js ie. use the `Dimensions` object directly.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
// in your class component
componentDidMount() {
    Dimensions.addEventListener("change", (handler) => this.setState({
    wHeight: handler.window.height,
    wWidth: handler.window.width
    })
}
```

Comment: cool, it works.. but only thing is that I can access the state in stylesheet, so I am using a global variable.. I console log the thing it seems changing the value but stylesheet is still not updating the latest value??

Comment: You're missing a parenthesis.

Comment: Use Dimensions.removeEventListener to remove the listener function in the useEffect. It could lead to memory issues reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions –

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can use this in your class based components to get the window `height` and `width`

Check this

```
    import {Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
    const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
    
        class ABC extends Comp {
        
        
        render(){
        const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width
        const screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
        return(
        )
        }
        
        }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
main:{
padding:screenWidth==25?20:30
}
})
```

Hope it helps, feel free for doubts

Comment: Hi thanks for the code, can I use these variable inside my stylesheets ?

Comment: its not working!

Comment: What's not working? can you share an expo snack for the same?

Comment: the width and height I got in stylesheet are different than in render, and it is not reflecting the latest change.. so it is not working

Comment: also I change the global const to var, and use that in the answer suggested by Yoav Karpassi, it seems working but the stylesheet still not getting the correct value or updating the view, can you help me out on this?